# Very simple powershell script not working in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda

I'm trying to learn how to use AWS Lambda and I have a lot of questions, but mainly I made an extremely simple PowerShell script for testing. Here's the code:

```
echo "Start"
$PSVersionTable
echo $PSVersionTable
[System.Console]::WriteLine($PSVersionTable)
[System.Console]::WriteLine("done")
```

Just testing different ways to return info.

For some reason Lambda forces me to put it in a zip file to upload it instead of uploading the script directly? Why?

Regardless, I got the script uploaded and as far as I can tell there's no "Go", "Start", "Run", or anything to actually start the script. But there's a "Test" option so I went that route. No idea what template I should use, so kept the default "hello-world" template and all the pre-filled key/values:

```json
{
    "key1": "value1"
    "key2": "value2"
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

When I test it, it throws this error:

> .NET binaries for Lambda function are not correctly installed in the /var/task directory of the image when the image was built. The /var/task directory is missing the required .deps.json file.

I thought the whole point of AWS Lambda was to run serverless code? Why do I now need to worry about verifying certain dependencies are in certain directories? That negates the whole point of it being serverless. Not to mention, when I built the function I chose the ".NET 6 (C#/PowerShell)" runtime--why would that not provide the binaries I need?

So what's the proper way to run a powershell script in AWS Lambda?

Comment: Add more code with the errors.  You are sending an HTTP Request and must follow the request format.  You are missing the content type.  You are sending json and a http header needs to be added indicating the body is json.  It looks like you are defaulting to text in the body of the http request.

Comment: "Serverless" just means it's some else's server.  You still need follow the rules to run your code.  The [Building Lambda functions with PowerShell docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-powershell.html) go into detail on what is required.

Comment: @jdweng so the JSON for the test is where the HTTP request/header/body/etc goes?

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: @jdweng the code is in the post

Comment: Not enough to help.  There are no Lambda functions posted which is what the error message indicates.

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand what more info you need. I didn't make any lambda functions, I'm trying to run powershell code which is in the post. Everything that I did is provided in the post. What lambda functions would I need? And how would I write them?

Comment: Then where is the variable $PSVersionTable set?  Where is the template added to the script?

Comment: @jdweng $PSVersionTable is an automatic variable. It's available in PowerShell by default and contains the PowerShell version you're running. What template are you referring to? If it's not in the post, I didn't do a template. This is exactly the reason for the post, I'm trying to find out what is missing to make it work.

Comment: If you use Write-Host instead of console do you get error?

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Lambda PowerShell experience today is built on top of the .NET Lambda runtime. You have to use the AWSLambdaPSCore module to take care of the packaging for you to make the PowerShell script be compatible with the .NET Lambda runtime. Here is the README for that module. https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/PowerShell

An alternative is there is a PowerShell Lambda layer you can install into your account that gives a more PowerShell native experience once you get setup the Lambda layers. Here is the info on that https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-powershell-custom-runtime-for-aws-lambda/

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this requirement so that helps a lot